# how to fix marker on physical view in open street map

Tags: angular, google-maps-markers, openstreetmap, leaflet.markercluster, angular-leaflet-directive

i am using open street map of leaflet template in my project.i have multiple markers but when i open map all marker are pointed on single point on map even they have different cordinates. and when i drag map then markers are not fix on map, all markers move on map.please provide solution to fix markers on map

```
createPhysicalMap(containerId, markers) {
    const map = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 100,
        minZoom: 2,
        zoom: 10,
        noWrap: true,
        attribution: ''
    });
    const phyMap = this.initialisePhysicalMap(containerId, markers, map);
    return phyMap;
}
```

i want to fix all markers to there cordinates when i drag and zoom in , zoom out in map

```
initialisePhysicalMap(containerId, markers, map) {
    // if previously created map, make its id null
    const container = L.DomUtil.get(containerId);
    if (container !== null) {
        container._leaflet_id = null;
    }
    let physicalMap;
    if (markers instanceof Array) {
        if (markers && markers.length) {
            // set map markers
            markers.forEach(marker => {
                physicalMap = L.map(containerId, {
                    center: new L.LatLng(marker.lat, marker.lng),
                    zoom: 13,
                    layers: [map],
                    worldCopyJump: false,
                    maxBounds: [[-90, -180], [90, 180]]
                });
                const mark = L.marker([marker.lat, marker.lng], { icon: this.markerIcon, title: marker.label ,draggable: false,dragging:false,autoPan: false}).addTo(physicalMap)
                .on('mouseover', function() {
                    const popupContent = `
                        <html>
                        <head>
                        <style>.....
                        </style>
                        <body>....
                        </body>
                        </head>
                        </html>`
                    const popup = this.bindPopup(popupContent);
                        popup.openPopup();
                        const popupContainer = document.getElementById('hover');
                        popupContainer.addEventListener('mouseout', function(event) {
                    const relatedTarget = event.relatedTarget as HTMLElement;
                    if (!popupContainer.contains(relatedTarget)) {
                        popup.closePopup();
                    }
                });
                });
            });
        }
```